# Numbers keep summing but does not stop summing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I made a program that allows the user to input how many integers they want to sum and I was able to get it but when the user goes again, it keeps adding to the previous sum when it should restart and add the new integers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//  ================

int main() {
    // Declared Variables 
    int num;
    int sum;
    int total = 0;
    char ans = 'y';

    //  ===========

    using namespace std; 
    // While loop which allows user to go again.
    while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
    {
        // Input for adding any number of integers 
        cout << "How many integer values would you like to sum? ";
        cin >> num;
        cout << endl;
        //  =========

        //  For Loop allows to add integers 
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter an integer value: ";
            cin >> sum;
            total += sum;


        }  // End for loop
        //  ==============

        //  Prints out the sum of the numbers 
        cout << "The sum is " << total << endl;
        cout << endl;

        // Asks the user if they want to go again
        cout << "Would you like to go again (y/n)? ";
        cin >> ans;
        cout << endl; 

        if (ans != 'y')
        {
            cout << "Bye..." << endl;
        }// End If statement
        //  ================

    }//  End while loop
    //  ==============

    cout << endl;
    return 0;  
}  // Function main()
//  =================
```

Comment: You have to reset `total`

Comment: That's the classical case to detect an error using the debugger while stepping through the code. Asking as a Stack Overflow question? Very arguable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move this line inside the while loop:

```
int total = 0;
```

I.e.:

```
while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
{
    int total = 0;

    // Input for adding any number of integers 
    cout << "How many integer values would you like to sum? ";
    ...
```

Comment: Upvoted, because this was the valid answer here in 1st place. I'm actually tempted to rollback  the accepted answer, to it's ugly [FGITW form](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38385989/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your while loop:

```
total = 0;
```

Here's a much shorter, improved version of your code.

```
int main()
{
    char ans;

    do {
        int n, sum = 0;        

        std::cout << "Enter the number of numbers\n";
        std::cin >> n;
        while (--n >= 0) {
            int x;
            std::cout << "Number? ";
            std::cin >> x;

            sum += x;
        }
        std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << "\nGo again?(y/n)\n";
        std::cin >> ans;
    } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');

    std::cout << "Bye\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `total = 0`.

Comment: @smarx Are we lacking semicola, or something is wrong with your keyboards guys?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My answer is not lacking any semicolons.

Comment: @smarx I primarily addressed your comment here, not your answer. Or was it you who received the downvote?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Did you downvote because i forgot a semicolon?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My comment on this answer didn't include a semicolon because I was correcting text that didn't include a semicolon.

Comment: It's pretty obvious a semi colon belongs there. This is not a compiler, but a  forum for humans to read. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @stackptr [Nothing more to say here ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385976/numbers-keep-summing-but-does-not-stop-summing/38385989?noredirect=1#comment64182183_38385986)